# How to Group Data by Month and Year in SSRS Report?

Tags: xml, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm working on an SSRS report where I need to group data by month and year. I have a datetime column in my dataset that contains the date and time for each record. I want to create a report that displays the data grouped by month and year, with a separate section for each month-year combination.

I've tried using the "Group Properties" and "Grouping and Sorting" options in SSRS, but I can't seem to figure out the correct expressions and settings to achieve the desired grouping. Can someone please guide me on how to accomplish this?

I expected this code to group the data by month and year, but it's not working as intended. The report displays the data without any grouping, and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions on how to achieve the desired grouping in my SSRS report. Thank you in advance!

```
<Table>
  <TablixRowHierarchy>
    <TablixMembers>
      <TablixMember>
        <Group Name="MonthGroup">
          <GroupExpressions>
            <GroupExpression>=Month(Fields!DateTimeColumn.Value)</GroupExpression>
          </GroupExpressions>
        </Group>
        <TablixMembers>
          <TablixMember>
            <Group Name="YearGroup">
              <GroupExpressions>
                <GroupExpression>=Year(Fields!DateTimeColumn.Value)</GroupExpression>
              </GroupExpressions>
            </Group>
            <TablixMembers>
              <TablixMember>
                <!-- Columns and data fields go here -->
              </TablixMember>
            </TablixMembers>
          </TablixMember>
        </TablixMembers>
      </TablixMember>
    </TablixMembers>
  </TablixRowHierarchy>
</Table>
```

Comment: Can you show a screen shot of the report design from Visual Studio or Report Builder and make sure you show the rowgroup panel below the main designer and the properties of each group. The expression sin the RDL snip you posted *look* OK but it's much easier to check when you can visually see the design.